# how can I show "please wait gif" image before the process is complete

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to show "please wait gif" image from img() class before the ListApp() class process is complete and then as soon as the process of that class is completed the screeen of ListApp should be displayed.

I was trying the following code but it is not starting the process of ListApp() class

**run1.py file**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from Option import OptionApp
import sys, time, threading
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from datetime import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList,ThreeLineListItem,ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import IconLeftWidget,ImageLeftWidget
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import csv
from os import path
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
import pandas as pd

kv = Builder.load_file("run1.kv")




class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    txt_input1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    txt_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):

        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''

        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:

            # self.root.ids.txt_input1.text = str(rv.data[index].get("text"))
            App.get_running_app().root.widget_1.ids.txt_input1.text = str(rv.data[index].get("text"))

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class DropDownWidget(BoxLayout):
    txt_input = ObjectProperty()
    rv = ObjectProperty()
    txt_input1 = ObjectProperty()


class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    txt_input = ObjectProperty()
    txt_input1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    flt_list = ObjectProperty()
    word_list = ListProperty()
    # this is the variable storing the number to which the look-up will start
    starting_no = NumericProperty(3)
    suggestion_text = ''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyTextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        # find all the occurrence of the word
        self.parent.ids.rv.data = []
        matches = [self.word_list[i] for i in range(len(self.word_list)) if
                   self.word_list[i][:self.starting_no] == value[:self.starting_no]]
        # display the data in the recycleview
        display_data = []
        for i in matches:
            display_data.append({'text': i})
        self.parent.ids.rv.data = display_data
        # ensure the size is okay
        if len(matches) <= 10:
            self.parent.height = (50 + (len(matches) * 20))
        else:
            self.parent.height = 240

    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if self.suggestion_text and keycode[1] == 'tab':
            self.insert_text(self.suggestion_text + ' ')
            return True
        return super(MyTextInput, self).keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)


class Body(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(Body, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        f = pd.read_csv("stoploss.csv")
        fl = len(f.index)
        file = pd.DataFrame(f, columns=['Stock Symbol', 'Purchase Price', 'Stock Name', 'Stop Loss(%)'])
        j = 0
        wl = []
        for i in range(fl):
            for index in range(1):
                columnSeriesObj = file.iloc[:, 2]
                # pp = iter(columnSeriesObj.values)
                # pp1 = next(pp)
                # print(pp1)

                wl.append(columnSeriesObj.values[i])

        tp = tuple(wl)
        print(str(tp))


        self.widget_1 = DropDownWidget(pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5},
                                       size_hint=(None, None), size=(600, 60))
        self.widget_1.ids.txt_input.word_list = wl
        self.widget_1.ids.txt_input.starting_no = 3

        self.add_widget(self.widget_1)
    





class signin(Screen):

    user_name = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):

        username = self.user_name.text
        print(username)
        sm.current = 'option_screen'

class option(Screen):

    def btn_addstock(self):
        sm.current = 'body_screen'

    def btn_stoplosslist(self):
        sm.canvas.clear()
        sm.current = 'Stoploss_ip'







class stockinput(Screen):
    stock_name = ObjectProperty(None)
    stock_symbol = ObjectProperty(None)
    purchase_price = ObjectProperty(None)
    stop_loss = ObjectProperty(None)


    def btn(self):
        end = datetime.today().date()
        start = end.year - 10
        start = datetime(start, datetime.today().month, datetime.today().day).date()
        uname = input("Enter user name: ")
        print("Stock Name:", self.stock_name.text, "Stock Symbol:", self.stock_symbol.text)
        print("Purchase Price:",self.purchase_price.text,"Stop Loss(%):",self.stop_loss.text)

        #write data to csv file

        # if path.exists("stoploss.csv"):
        #     myFile = open('stoploss.csv', 'a')
        # else:
        #     myFile = open('stoploss.csv', 'w')
        file_name = stockinput.uname + "_stoploss.csv"
        if path.exists(file_name):
            with open(file_name, "a+", newline='')as newFile :
                fieldnames = ["Stock Name", "Stock Symbol", "Purchase Price", "Stop Loss(%)"]
                newFileWriter = csv.DictWriter(newFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                newFileWriter.writerow({"Stock Name" : self.stock_name.text,"Stock Symbol" : self.stock_symbol.text,"Purchase Price" : self.purchase_price.text,"Stop Loss(%)" : self.stop_loss.text})

        else:
            myFile = open(file_name, 'w+')
            myData = [["Stock Name", "Stock Symbol", "Purchase Price", "Stop Loss(%)"],[self.stock_name.text, self.stock_symbol.text, self.purchase_price.text, self.stop_loss.text]]

            with myFile:
                writer = csv.writer(myFile)
                writer.writerows(myData)

        df = web.DataReader(self.stock_symbol.text, 'yahoo', start, end,)
        print(df.tail())

        self.stock_name.text = ""
        self.stock_symbol.text = ""
        self.purchase_price.text = ""
        self.stop_loss.text = ""

f = pd.read_csv("stoploss.csv")
file = pd.DataFrame(f, columns=['Stock Symbol','Purchase Price','Stock Name','Stop Loss(%)'])


class img(Screen):
    def build(self,**kwargs):
        super(img, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        screen = self
        image = Image(source='please_wait.gif')
        screen.add_widget(image)

class ListApp(Screen):

    # def imgpr(self,**kwargs):
    #     super(ListApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    #
    #         time.sleep(0.1)

    # t = threading.Thread(target=imgpr)
    # t.start()
    def build(self,**kwargs):
        super(ListApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        flag = True


        screen = self
        # if flag:
        #
        #
        #     sm.add_widget(ListApp(name='Stoploss_ip'))


        end = datetime(2020, 12, 14)
        start = datetime(2020, 12, 14)

        btn = Button(text="Back",
                     font_size="20sp",

                     background_color=(255/255, 229/255, 204/255, 1),
                     color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                     size=(12, 12),
                     size_hint=(.1, .05),
                     pos=(600, 500))
        btn.bind(on_press=lambda *args: setattr(sm, 'current', "option_screen"))

        scroll = ScrollView()
        list_view = MDList()


        scroll.add_widget(list_view)



        i = 0
        fl = len(file.index)
        try:
            for index in range(fl):

                for index in range(1):
                    columnSeriesObj2 = file.iloc[:, 0]

                    df = web.DataReader(columnSeriesObj2.values[i],'yahoo', start, end,retry_count=3)
                    print(df.head())
                    Objname = file.iloc[:, 2]
                    columnSeriesObj = df.iloc[:, 3]
                    columnSeriesObj1 = file.iloc[:, 1]
                    ObjStoploss = file.iloc[:, 3]

                    cp = iter(columnSeriesObj.values)
                    pp = iter(columnSeriesObj1.values)
                    pp1 = next(pp)
                    cp1 = columnSeriesObj.values[0]


                    sl = columnSeriesObj1.values[i] - (columnSeriesObj1.values[i] * (ObjStoploss.values[i]/100))


                    if cp1 <= sl:
                        image = ImageLeftWidget(source='loss.png')
                        items = ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Alert sale " + Objname.values[i], secondary_text='Close price: '+str(cp1),
                                                            tertiary_text='Stoploss: ' + str(sl))
                        items.add_widget(image)
                        list_view.add_widget(items)



                        i=i+1


                    else:
                        image = ImageLeftWidget(source='profit.jpg')
                        items = ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Chill " + Objname.values[i],
                                                            secondary_text='Close price: ' + str(cp1),
                                                            tertiary_text='Stoploss: ' + str(sl))
                        items.add_widget(image)
                        list_view.add_widget(items)


                        i=i+1
        except ConnectionAbortedError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout!!!!...Check your Internet connection")
        except KeyError:
            pass

        except:
            print("Something went wrong")
        print("Done")

        # flag = False
        # if flag ==False:
        screen.add_widget(scroll)
        screen.add_widget(btn)
        # return screen


class WindowsManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(signin(name='signin_screen'))
sm.add_widget(option(name='option_screen'))
sm.add_widget(stockinput(name='stockinput_screen'))
sm.add_widget(img(name='image_screen'))
sm.add_widget(ListApp(name='Stoploss_ip'))
sm.add_widget(Body(name='body_screen'))

class run1(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run1().run()
```

**run1.kv file**

```
<WindowsManager>:
    signin:
    option:
    stockinput:
    ListApp:
    Body:


<Body>:
    name: 'body_screen'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 188/255, 143/255, 145/255, 1

        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<DropDownWidget>:
    id: DropDownWidget
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:(1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            # pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    # orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: 20
    txt_input: txt_input
    rv: rv

    txt_input1: txt_input1
    MyTextInput:
        id: txt_input1
        pos: 400,300
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
    MyTextInput:
        id: txt_input
        hint_text:'Enter here'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
    RV:
        id: rv




<MyTextInput>:
    id: MyTextInput

    readonly: False
    multiline: False

<SelectableLabel>:

    id: SelectableLabel

    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    color: 0,0,0,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 1, .5) if self.selected else (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            # pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:


    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,.2

        Line:
            rectangle: self.x +1 , self.y, self.width - 2, self.height -2


    bar_width: 10
    scroll_type:['bars']
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(20)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: False
<signin>:

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 164/255, 66/255, 220/255, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    name: 'signin_screen'

    user_name: user_name



    GridLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .75, 'center_y': .15}
        row_force_default : True
        row_default_height : 50
        col_force_default : True
        col_default_width : 400
        spacing: '15dp'
        cols: 1

        TextInput:
            id: user_name
            multiline:False
            size_hint: 5.0 ,.1

            hint_text: "Email_ID"

        Button:
            text:"Submit"
            font_size: 20
            color:0,0,0,1

            size_hint: .5 ,.3
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (255/255, 153/255, 71/255, 1)
            on_press : root.btn()





        Label:
            text:"Please Do not change the Email_ID. Data will be saved as per your Email_ID"
            pos: 180,80

<option>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 138/255, 104/255, 175/255, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    name: 'option_screen'

    GridLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .83, 'center_y': .18}
        row_force_default : True
        row_default_height : 100
        col_force_default : True
        col_default_width : 250
        spacing: '20dp'


        cols:1

        Button:
            text:"Add Stock"
            color:0,0,0,1
            font_size: 18
            size_hint: .1 ,.1
            pos: 150,150
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (204/255, 0, 204/255, 1)

            on_press : root.manager.current = 'body_screen'

        Button:
            text:"Check Stoploss"
            color:0,0,0,1
            font_size: 18
            size_hint: .1 ,.1
            pos: 250,120
            background_normal: ''
            background_color:(127/255, 193/255, 184/255, 1)


            on_press : root.manager.current = 'Stoploss_ip'




<stockinput>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 188/255, 143/255, 145/255, 1

        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    name: 'stockinput_screen'
    stock_name: stock_name
    stock_symbol: stock_symbol
    purchase_price: purchase_price
    stop_loss: stop_loss

    GridLayout:

        pos_hint: {'center_x': .67, 'center_y': .2}
        row_force_default : True
        row_default_height : 40
        col_force_default : True
        col_default_width : 250
        spacing: '10dp'
        cols:2



#            pos_hint: {'center_x': .53, 'center_y': .12}
#            row_force_default : True
#            row_default_height : 30
#            col_force_default : True
#            col_default_width : 250
#            spacing: '20dp'

        Label:
            text: "Stock Name: "

        TextInput:
            id: stock_name
            multiline:False

        Label:
            text: "Stock Symbol: "

        TextInput:
            id: stock_symbol
            multiline:False

        Label:
            text: "Purchase Price: "

        TextInput:
            id: purchase_price
            multiline:False

        Label:
            text: "Stop Loss(%): "

        TextInput:
            id: stop_loss
            multiline:False

        Button:
            text:"Submit"
            color:102/255, 204/255, 0, 1
            font_size:18
            background_color: (204/255, 0, 102/255, 1)
            on_press: root.btn()
        Button:
            text:"Back"
            color:0,0,0,1
            font_size:18
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (204/255, 102/255, 0, 1)
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'option_screen'

<img>:
    name: 'image_screen'
    on_enter:root.build()

<ListApp>:

    name: 'Stoploss_ip'

    on_enter:root.build()
```

****update**
I tried adding 2 lines in build() method and its showing the images now.I think its preloading the images and saving them in cache.

```
class ListApp(Screen):


    def build(self):
        self.popup = Popup(title='Calculating Stoploss', content=Image(source='please_wait.gif'))
        self.profit = ImageLeftWidget(source='profit.jpg')
        self.loss = ImageLeftWidget(source='loss.png')
        self.popup.open()
        # Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.actual_build))

        threading.Thread(target=self.actual_build).start()
    def actual_build(self):

        screen = self

        end = datetime.today().date()
        start = end

        btn = Button(text="Back",
                     font_size="20sp",

                     background_color=(255/255, 229/255, 204/255, 1),
                     color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                     size=(12, 12),
                     size_hint=(.1, .05),
                     pos=(600, 500))
        btn.bind(on_press=lambda *args: setattr(sm, 'current', "option_screen"))

        scroll = ScrollView()
        list_view = MDList()


        scroll.add_widget(list_view)



        i = 0
        fl = len(file.index)
        try:
            for index in range(fl):

                for index in range(1):
                    columnSeriesObj2 = file.iloc[:, 0]

                    df = web.DataReader(columnSeriesObj2.values[i],'yahoo', start, end,retry_count=3)
                    print(df.head())
                    Objname = file.iloc[:, 2]
                    columnSeriesObj = df.iloc[:, 3]
                    columnSeriesObj1 = file.iloc[:, 1]
                    ObjStoploss = file.iloc[:, 3]

                    cp = iter(columnSeriesObj.values)
                    pp = iter(columnSeriesObj1.values)
                    pp1 = next(pp)
                    cp1 = columnSeriesObj.values[0]


                    sl = columnSeriesObj1.values[i] - (columnSeriesObj1.values[i] * (ObjStoploss.values[i]/100))


                    if cp1 <= sl:
                        image = ImageLeftWidget(source='loss.png')
                        items = ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Alert sale " + Objname.values[i], secondary_text='Close price: '+str(cp1),
                                                            tertiary_text='Stoploss: ' + str(sl))
                        items.add_widget(image)
                        list_view.add_widget(items)



                        i=i+1


                    else:
                        image = ImageLeftWidget(source='profit.jpg')
                        items = ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Chill " + Objname.values[i],
                                                            secondary_text='Close price: ' + str(cp1),
                                                            tertiary_text='Stoploss: ' + str(sl))
                        items.add_widget(image)
                        list_view.add_widget(items)


                        i=i+1
        except ConnectionAbortedError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout!!!!...Check your Internet connection")
        except KeyError:
            pass

        except:
            pass
            # print("Something went wrong")
        print("Done")
        # screen.add_widget(screen.scroll)
        # screen.add_widget(btn)
        
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(screen.finish_build, scroll, btn))
        
        screen.popup.dismiss()

    def finish_build(self, scroll, btn, dt):
        screen = self
        screen.add_widget(scroll)
        screen.add_widget(btn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are triggering the `build()` method by using the `on_enter` attribute, you can accomplish what you want by using that method.

First, you are calling:

```
super(ListApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

from the `build()` method. You should not call that `super` method except from within an `__init__()` method override. So that line should be removed. Since you have not written an `__init__()` method for `ListApp`, there is no need to call the super class `__init__()`.

I suggest renaming your `build()` method to `actual_build()` like this:

```
def actual_build(self, *args):
```

and define a new `build()` method as:

```
def build(self, **kwargs):
    self.popup = Popup(title='Preparing ListApp', content=Image(source='please_wait.gif', anim_delay=0.05))
    self.popup.open()
    threading.Thread(target=self.actual_build).start()
```

The above method displays the animated gif, and starts the `actual_build()` method (formerly named `build()`).

Then, modify the `actual_build()` method as:

```
def actual_build(self, *args):
    # super(ListApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    flag = True


    screen = self
    # if flag:
    #
    #
    #     sm.add_widget(ListApp(name='Stoploss_ip'))


    end = datetime(2020, 12, 14)
    start = datetime(2020, 12, 14)

    btn = Button(text="Back",
                 font_size="20sp",

                 background_color=(255/255, 229/255, 204/255, 1),
                 color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                 size=(12, 12),
                 size_hint=(.1, .05),
                 pos=(600, 500))
    btn.bind(on_press=lambda *args: setattr(sm, 'current', "option_screen"))

    scroll = ScrollView()
    list_view = MDList()


    scroll.add_widget(list_view)



    i = 0
    fl = len(file.index)
    try:
        for index in range(fl):

            for index in range(1):
                columnSeriesObj2 = file.iloc[:, 0]

                df = web.DataReader(columnSeriesObj2.values[i],'yahoo', start, end,retry_count=3)
                print(df.head())
                Objname = file.iloc[:, 2]
                columnSeriesObj = df.iloc[:, 3]
                columnSeriesObj1 = file.iloc[:, 1]
                ObjStoploss = file.iloc[:, 3]

                cp = iter(columnSeriesObj.values)
                pp = iter(columnSeriesObj1.values)
                pp1 = next(pp)
                cp1 = columnSeriesObj.values[0]


                sl = columnSeriesObj1.values[i] - (columnSeriesObj1.values[i] * (ObjStoploss.values[i]/100))


                if cp1 <= sl:
                    image = ImageLeftWidget(source='loss.png')
                    items = ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Alert sale " + Objname.values[i], secondary_text='Close price: '+str(cp1),
                                                        tertiary_text='Stoploss: ' + str(sl))
                    items.add_widget(image)
                    list_view.add_widget(items)



                    i=i+1


                else:
                    image = ImageLeftWidget(source='profit.jpg')
                    items = ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Chill " + Objname.values[i],
                                                        secondary_text='Close price: ' + str(cp1),
                                                        tertiary_text='Stoploss: ' + str(sl))
                    items.add_widget(image)
                    list_view.add_widget(items)


                    i=i+1
    except ConnectionAbortedError:
        print("Check your Internet connection")
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("Check your Internet connection")
    except ConnectionError:
        print("Check your Internet connection")
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print("Check your Internet connection")
    except TimeoutError:
        print("Timeout!!!!...Check your Internet connection")
    except KeyError:
        pass

    except:
        print("Something went wrong")

    # flag = False
    # if flag ==False:
    # screen.add_widget(scroll)
    # screen.add_widget(btn)

    # schedule the code that must be run on the main thread
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.finish_build, scroll, btn))

    # dismiss the animated gif
    self.popup.dismiss()
```

The above `actual_build()` method does everything that the original `build()` method did, except for the actual changes to the GUI (that must be done on the main thread). At the end of this method, a call to `finish_build()` is scheduled, and the animated gif `Popup` is dismissed.

Finally, add a `finish_build()` method that does the actual GUI changes:

```
def finish_build(self, scroll, btn, dt):
    screen = self
    screen.add_widget(scroll)
    screen.add_widget(btn)
```

Comment: thank you sir.. But After changing the code as you advised the images I was using in listview as an Icon like "loss.jpg" and "profit.png" are not displayed. they are just total black images. what could be the issue?.

Comment: I was unable to run your entire code when developing my answer. You may need to restructure those methods to do just the file processing in the `actual_build()` method and place all of the widget creation in the `finish_build()` method. If you do too much processing on the main thread, your animated gif will not get animated.

Comment: Okay.. I got it.. Thanks sir

Comment: I tried that too. But as you can see my code .. the image gets added in ImageLeftWidget when the if statement is true while for loop is iterating. and it is the main part of actual_build(). so how can I add that in finish_build()

Comment: I tried changing the code "threading.Thread(target=self.actual_build).start()"  to  Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.actual_build)) in build method. now it is showing those images. but issue is gif anime is not playing. it look like a image only. I dont know is freezed or not playing the anime. what should I do?

Comment: Changing `threading.Thread(target=self.actual_build).start()"`to `Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.actual_build)) ` defeats the purpose of separating the `build()` method into pieces. The idea was to get `actual_build()` off the main thread, but `Clock.schedule_once()` puts it back on the main thread. If you could provide a copy of the `stoploss.csv` file, I may be able to run your code and provide better answers. In general, for anything in `actual_build()` that directly affects the GUI display, write a new (very short) method that just makes that GUI change and call it with `Clock.schedule`.

Comment: here is the link for stoploss.csv file. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10lq_DCGjuhhm4_k0j9VkD_xr4OyoqHoS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: also please see the updated question. will that code affect the memory in future. is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

Now that I can actually run your code, I have an updated answer. First, some of the `ListApp` screen can be constructed in the `kv` file as:

```
<ListApp>:
    name: 'Stoploss_ip'

    on_enter:root.build()

    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: list_view
    
    Button:
        text: "Back"
        font_size: "20sp"
        background_color: (255/255, 229/255, 204/255, 1)
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        size: (12, 12)
        size_hint: (.1, .05)
        pos: (600, 500)
        on_press: root.manager.current = "option_screen"
```

Then the `ListApp` class can be:

```
class ListApp(Screen):
    built = BooleanProperty(False)

    def build(self):
        if self.built:
            return
        self.built = True
        self.popup = Popup(title='Calculating Stoploss', content=Image(source='please_wait.gif'))
        self.popup.open()
        threading.Thread(target=self.actual_build).start()

    def actual_build(self):
        end = datetime.today().date()
        start = end

        i = 0
        fl = len(file.index)
        try:
            for index in range(fl):

                for index in range(1):
                    columnSeriesObj2 = file.iloc[:, 0]

                    df = web.DataReader(columnSeriesObj2.values[i],'yahoo', start, end,retry_count=3)
                    print(df.head())
                    Objname = file.iloc[:, 2]
                    columnSeriesObj = df.iloc[:, 3]
                    columnSeriesObj1 = file.iloc[:, 1]
                    ObjStoploss = file.iloc[:, 3]

                    cp = iter(columnSeriesObj.values)
                    pp = iter(columnSeriesObj1.values)
                    pp1 = next(pp)
                    cp1 = columnSeriesObj.values[0]
                    sl = columnSeriesObj1.values[i] - (columnSeriesObj1.values[i] * (ObjStoploss.values[i]/100))

                    if cp1 <= sl:
                        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.add_loss, Objname.values[i], str(cp1), str(sl)))
                        i=i+1
                    else:
                        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.add_profit, Objname.values[i], str(cp1), str(sl)))
                        i=i+1
        except ConnectionAbortedError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout!!!!...Check your Internet connection")
        except KeyError:
            pass

        except:
            pass
            # print("Something went wrong")
        print("Done")
        self.popup.dismiss()

    def add_loss(self, name, close_price, stop_loss, dt):
            image = ImageLeftWidget(source='loss.png')
            items = ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Alert sale " + name, secondary_text='Close price: '+close_price,
                                                tertiary_text='Stoploss: ' + stop_loss)
            items.add_widget(image)
            self.ids.list_view.add_widget(items)

    def add_profit(self, name, close_price, stop_loss, dt):
            image = ImageLeftWidget(source='profit.jpg')
            items = ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Chill " + name,
                                                secondary_text='Close price: ' + close_price,
                                                tertiary_text='Stoploss: ' + stop_loss)
            items.add_widget(image)
            self.ids.list_view.add_widget(items)
```

The main items changed are that the list and the back button are built in the 'kv', and the items for the list are built using `Clock.schedule_once()`. There is no longer any need for the `finish_build()` method.

Also, note that I have added a `built` attribute that keeps track of whether the screen has been built, so that the screen doesn't get built multiple times. If it was built multiple times, the items in the list would get added repeatedly.

Comment: @Jahn Anderson. Thank you so much

Comment: new question regarding recycleview [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65371164/how-can-i-change-background-color-of-selected-item-in-recycleview-i-also-i-want)

Comment: sir did you check my new question?  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65371164/how-can-i-change-background-color-of-selected-item-in-recycleview-also-i-want-i)

Comment: please checkout the question sir

Comment: you added a built attribute that keeps track of whether the screen has been built. but What is I want to place a refresh button there then how can I reload the same process without repetition of items.