# How can I search in recycleview

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How can I search in recycleview with updated review .I can also search now. But when I type  3 alphabets in txt_input it search for the same result. and gives the list which contains those 3 alphabets.

But i want to make as a search engine. so if I type "TAT" it will show me TATA MOTORS PVT LTD,Tata Elxsi Limited,Tata Steel Limited,etc. But when I type "TATA MO" it doesnot update the recycleview with new search suggestions.

How can I achieve that kind of updated result every time add alphabets?

**test.py file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
import pandas as pd

Builder.load_string('''
<Body>:
    name: 'body_screen'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:(1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            # pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<DropDownWidget>:
    name: 'DropDownWidget'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:(1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            # pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    # orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: 20
    txt_input: txt_input
    rv: rv
    # txt_input1: txt_input1
    MyTextInput:
        id: txt_input1
        pos: 400,300
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
    MyTextInput:
        id: txt_input
        hint_text:'Enter here'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
    RV:
        id: rv
    



<MyTextInput>:
    name: 'MyTextInput'
    readonly: False
    multiline: False

<SelectableLabel>:
    name: 'SelectableLabel'
    id: SelectableLabel
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    color: 0,0,0,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 1, .5) if self.selected else (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            # pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,.2

        Line:
            rectangle: self.x +1 , self.y, self.width - 2, self.height -2


    bar_width: 10
    scroll_type:['bars']
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(20)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: False

        ''')


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior,Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    txt_input1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    txt_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''

        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:

            App.get_running_app().root.widget_1.ids.txt_input1.text = str(rv.data[index].get("text"))


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class DropDownWidget(BoxLayout):
    txt_input = ObjectProperty()
    rv = ObjectProperty()
    txt_input1 = ObjectProperty()


class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    txt_input = ObjectProperty()
    txt_input1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    flt_list = ObjectProperty()
    word_list = ListProperty()
    # this is the variable storing the number to which the look-up will start
    starting_no = NumericProperty(3)
    suggestion_text = ''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyTextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        # find all the occurrence of the word
        self.parent.ids.rv.data = []
        matches = [self.word_list[i] for i in range(len(self.word_list)) if
                   self.word_list[i][:self.starting_no] == value[:self.starting_no]]
        # display the data in the recycleview
        display_data = []
        for i in matches:
            display_data.append({'text': i})
        self.parent.ids.rv.data = display_data
        # ensure the size is okay
        if len(matches) <= 10:
            self.parent.height = (50 + (len(matches) * 20))
        else:
            self.parent.height = 240

    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if self.suggestion_text and keycode[1] == 'tab':
            self.insert_text(self.suggestion_text + ' ')
            return True
        return super(MyTextInput, self).keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)


class Body(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        f = pd.read_csv("stoploss.csv")
        fl = len(f.index)
        file = pd.DataFrame(f, columns=['Stock Symbol', 'Purchase Price', 'Stock Name', 'Stop Loss(%)'])
        j = 0
        wl = []
        for i in range(fl):
            for index in range(1):
                columnSeriesObj = file.iloc[:, 2]
                # pp = iter(columnSeriesObj.values)
                # pp1 = next(pp)
                # print(pp1)

                wl.append(columnSeriesObj.values[i])

        tp = tuple(wl)
        print(str(tp))

        # def convertTuple(tup):
        #     str = ''.join(tup)
        #     return str
        # print(convertTuple(tp))
        super(Body, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.widget_1 = DropDownWidget(pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5},
                                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(600, 60))
        self.widget_1.ids.txt_input.word_list = wl
        self.widget_1.ids.txt_input.starting_no = 3

        self.add_widget(self.widget_1)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Body()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i am answering my own question.I found the solution from google kivy groups.

change change of code will do the thing.

**change the code from:**

```
matches = [self.word_list[i] for i in range(len(self.word_list)) if
                   self.word_list[i][:self.starting_no] == value[:self.starting_no]]
```

**to:**

```
matches = [word for word in self.word_list
                   if word[:len(value)].lower() == value[:len(value)].lower()]
```